# Python convert #U0048 style unicode to normal string

Tags: python, unicode

I am trying to convert a string that contains unicode-style formatting, like:

```
'#U0048#U0045#U004C#U004C#U004F'
```

What would be the most pythonic way to convert this to:

```
'HELLO'
```

thanks!

Comment: Does the string just contain `#Uxxxx` characters (but may contain other characters) or is it composed of only `#Uxxxx` sequences?

Comment: only `#Uxxxx` characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace `#U` with `\u` to create unicode's codes

```
\u0048\u0045\u004C\u004C\u004F
```

and then you can encode it to bytes and decode it back using `'unicode_escape'` or `'raw_unicode_escape'`

```
print('#U0048#U0045#U004C#U004C#U004F'.replace('#U', '\\u').encode().decode('unicode_escape'))
```

---

Doc: [codecs - Text Encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings)